# Where can I find createsample.exe utility?

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing, object-detection

I would like to create my own haar-classifier in order to perform a object detection. I follow [this](http://note.sonots.com/SciSoftware/haartraining.html#t1a1f262) tutorial on creating your own haar-classifier cascades.

The tutorial requires utilities such as `createsample.exe` which, according to [their documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/user_guide/ug_traincascade.html) should be included with OpenCV package.

I have searched the entire `OpenCV-2.4.6-android-sdk`folder to find it but no luck.

Anybody knows where to find it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oh, it's not included in the OpenCV-2.4.6-android-sdk

you have to either

- get a [binary package for your os](http://opencv.org/downloads.html)
- or compile from [source](https://github.com/itseez/opencv) ( cmake required, too )

Comment: Thanks for clarification. I have downloaded the OpenCV package for Windows and located haartraining.cpp and createsamples.cpp. Could you please tell me how can I now build it from the source so I can get the executable files?

Comment: there' no opencv_haartraining.exe in the bin folder ? in that case, you'll need to run cmake in that folder, to generate the proj / makefile

Comment: I have installed cmake and tried to generate the .exe files from D:/OpenCV/apps/haartraining folder, I get error: "Error in configuration process, files may be invalid"